# How to invoke front camera intent while building an android apk in Android O Build, (Android 8.0)

Tags: android-camera, android-8.0-oreo

I am building an Android app which requires an intent to invoke front facing camera when device is lifted to certain height to take selfie. I am working on Android O (Android 8.0). So Please suggest me an easy way to invoke the front camera. I referred old codes but none of them were related to Android O.

Here is the code I've tried so far:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT); 
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.LENS_FACING_FRONT", 1); 
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true); 
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Please add any code you have tried so far and highlight the area where you are having trouble.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.LENS_FACING_FRONT", 1);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

Comment: Let me rephrase that, please add any code you have tried so far to your question. I'll take care of it this time, next time use the "edit" link that is under your question to add more detail.

Answer (score 1):

> I am building an Android app which requires an intent to invoke front facing camera when device is lifted to certain height to take selfie.

Use the camera APIs (`android.hardware.Camera` or `android.hardware.camera2.*`). Or, use a library that wraps around them and makes their use easier, such as Fotoapparat or CameraKit-Android.

> I referred old codes but none of them were related to Android O.

There is nothing about your problem that has anything to do with Android 8.0.